# Specific template for subcategory of custom taxomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I've a custom post type that I manage with a custom taxonomy.
I've made a template: taxonomy-brand.php, to show the top level categories of the taxonomy.
Now I'd need to show the subcategories of each of these, in another different template.
I guess that it's possible to use the template_include filter, but I can't implement precisely and which condition to evaluate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) hook to load a specific template for your taxonomy. You would need to change out any instances of `my-taxonomy` with your specific custom taxonomy and switch out the `brand-subcategories.php` with whatever your template name is.

```
/**
 * Force Taxonomy Subcategories to new template
 *
 * @param String $template - Expected template path
 *
 * @return String $template
 */
function wpse303717_subcategory_template( $template ) {

    // We're not on a taxonomy page
    if( ! ( is_tax() && is_tax( 'my-taxonomy' ) ) ) {
        return $template;
    }

    // Grab the queried object, _should_ be a term but make sure.
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();

    // We either don't have the right object OR we're on a top level category becuase $term->parent === 0
    if( isset( $queried_object->parent ) && empty( $queried_object->parent ) ) {
        return $template;
    }

    // Our template could be located anywhere, we could store it in a subdirectory but 
    // we would need to specify a relative path from the theme root to it.
    // Example: 'templates/brand-subcategories.php'
    if( false !== ( $new_template = locate_template( 'brand-subcategories.php' ) ) ) {
        $template = $new_template;
    }

    return $template;

}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse303717_subcategory_template' );
```

If you want to load a specific template per subcategory you would need to test against `$queried_object->term_id` vs what you expect. Though do note that your client could delete these terms which would throw off your code.

Comment: Hy Howdy!
Thank you so much, you give me a big help. 
I need just this kind of solution.